# Can't play this video error in android WebView using RTSP stream

Tags: android, webview, rtsp

My App has a WebView which loads a simple html. However, this html links to a rtsp live video stream and the WebView is able to load it, but when I click on one video it shows as loading the player but after some time getting message "Can't play this video.. When I open the rtsp link in the native Android browser, it loads and works fine so I know it's not the video stream being incompatible. Is there something within WebView which can be enabled to allow the rtsp video stream to be played? I tried this in both emulator and original device.
Thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
private Button button;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    final Context context = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

}
```

}

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity 
{
    private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://myurl.com/");
}
```

}

Comment: Is this on an emulator or a real device?

Comment: Tried with emulator and on real device. Same error.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: How can you play rtsp video stream using simple html? I was trying to find solution for this without success. So I'm really interested in.

Comment: http://myurl.com replaces my original webpage link.

Comment: Hope your app has the USE_INTERNET permission enabled in the manifest file. Also if its OK with your requirement  try the experiment with a WebChromeClient instead of a simple webViewClient.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to redirect the stream to a video player using:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("rtsp")) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
});
```